# Creating a Raffle Platform with ETH

Tags: contract-development

I want to basically create a raffle system through ETH where I can essentially have people send "entries" to. eth or. Crypto address or addresses to raffle of digital assets such as NFT or domain names.

Is this possible and what is the complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. You would have a smart contract to which you give the NFT, along with a payable function for entering the raffle, which assigns a certain number of 'tickets' depending on how much ether was sent (in reality, the tickets are virtual, and represent the "weight" given to the user in the random selection of the winner) . This function would also only accept transactions up to a certain point in time. Then, you have a permissioned function that generates a pseudo-random number, which is used to select a winning ticket, and to send the NFT to the owner of that ticket.

Complexity is relative. Someone reasonably proficient at smart contract development should be able to do this without too much difficulty.

If you're looking for help implementing this, I encourage you to take a shot, and feel free to post any specific questions you have here (along with your code, what it does, and what it should do).

Comment: Thanks so much! I know nothing about actually programming and wanting to learn. I see an issue being the gas fees. Would someone need to pay a gas fee just to buy "tickets" and then another gas fee to execute the raffle? More concerned on the buying tickets as that may jeopardize the fundamentals fo a raffle which is to pay less for something at the opportunity to gain more. I guess if that was the case you would want the person to be able to buy tickets in mass and then store them in an account to be redeemed later?

Comment: Could you provide example links of (d)apps that facilitate raffle trading, for example, of NFTs?